# rails rails3-jquery-autocomplete gem renders the page instead of showing autocomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, render

I have a controller `Posts` which i try to autocomplete the post types and i have added under the first line of the controller this code

```
autocomplete :post, :post_type
```

then in the routes folder

```
  resources :posts do
    get :find_user_post_type, :on => :collection
  end

  resources :posts, :except => [:new, :create, :index]
```

and in the view

```
<%= f.autocomplete_field :post_type, find_user_post_type_posts_path %>
```

but when i type something in the field it simply renders the whole page i am instead of showing me matches of the autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the gem's JS correctly, depending on whether it is Rails 3.0 or 3.1?

According to the gem's docs, you need to set your action name based on the `autocomplete :post, :post_type` defined in your controller, like so:

```
# routes.rb
resources :posts, :except => [:new, :create, :index] do
    get :autocomplete_post_type, :on => :collection
end
```